# How can I add custom action for related workflow in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to add custom action like renaming document for related workflow item on MY Tasks page in alfresco share(Image provided).

[please refer below attached image, I want to add custom rename action with OOTB actions provided in right side of image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQg42.png).

Please provide required steps and code snippets if possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you can start with Jeff Potts tutorial : https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/actions/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: What will you do if your workflow has many documents attached? Seems like this could get ugly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can find task-details-actions code in the js file at below location,

```
<alf_home>\tomcat\webapps\share\components\workflow\task-details-actions.js
```

Override this file and add your custom action and do what you wanted to do.